# Add a new action to existing controller or add a new action to a new controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

RoR4 app. I have a page X which shows pricing stuff in an eCommerce website. So there is a pricing controller with index page showing the pricing content. There is a purchase button which needs to do following things:

1. If clicked, check whether the user is authenticated
2. If authenticated, take them to third party services for credit card information
3. On successful purchase, redirect the flow back to original eCommerce site

My dilemma: 
Should I add a new purchase controller? or add a new method purchase in existing controller of pricing.

Comment: I lean towards new controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends whether you want your app to be RESTful or not. Even if your pricing controller currently has only index action, in the future you might want to create a `new/edit` actions (to add prices), and therefore corresponding `create/update` actions.

Of course, if you don't want to be RESTful then you can add whatever methods you want. However, I think it is just a good practice to follow RESTful pattern. Such design has well defined and recognized semantics, and also keeps you from cluttering your controllers.

So, if you decide to go with a purchase controller, I would advise you to do the following:

1. Use `create` action as the destination for your purchase button.
2. On that `create` action add a `before_action` filter that will check for authentication.
3. Here I am not sure how exactly your interface with the third party is done, but I suggest you to record into your database all the important information about your transaction/purchase with some key, and only then execute your third-party purchase call.
4. On successful or unsuccessful purchase, hopefully, you can ask your third-party to redirect back to the `update` action in your purchase controller where you can update your record from step 3 with the return information (I prefer to save the whole response body too), and then depending on the status redirect internally to your pricing page in case of success or to some error processing page.

I am not saying that it is the only possible solution. However, from my previous experience I learned that keeping detailed transaction log in your own database is very useful for troubleshooting issues in the future.

So, the final answer is to prefer a separate controller over adding an unRESTful method that does not exactly fit to your existing controller.

Comment: thank you, I will go ahead with this solution :) very nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is good to have another controller because the name of the controller is pricing controller which I think not much tells the concern about the payments or transactions.

how about having new controller as `payments_controller.rb` or `transactions_controller.rb`

pricing name itself indicates some price related stuff where payments or transactions name indicates more close purpose of the functionality.